# Absolutely-positioned div not displaying with print stylesheet applied

Tags: css, printing

I am trying to add print functionality to one of our web maps, and am having trouble getting an absolutely-positioned div to display when I print. It displays correctly on my page, even when just the print stylesheet is applied to the page. But when I print it doesn't show up at all.

Rather than trying to add all the code here, I just put up a quick demo page to demonstrate the problem: http://maps.nps.gov/maps/rich/footstepsofhistory. To see the problem:

1. Load the page
2. Click on a point on the map
3. Try to print it

The print capability works exactly as expected, other than the fact that the InfoBox does not display.

Any help is much appreciated, and I can supply more information, if needed.

Comment: It worked fine for me in Firefox 5.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't tested in Firefox 5. It does *kind of work in Firefox 5, although the InfoBox is positioned incorrectly. It doesn't work at all in Chrome, Safari, or Internet Explorer. It's strange: I am seeing two very different results when I compare Firefox 5 and these other browsers, so I'm going to div in deeper to try and correct the discrepancies.

Comment: My bad, I was wrong. The only difference is that the InfoBox displays in Firefox and not in the other web browsers.